# C# how to resize terminal in console application,not forms

Tags: c#, terminal, console, console-application

C# how to resize terminal in console application..
i can't find how to resize my output window on console application

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Console.SetWindowSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setwindowsize(v=vs.110).aspx) method of Console class to set the size of window of the console application. You can also set the [Console.WindowWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.windowwidth(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Console.WindowHeight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.windowheight.aspx)

```
 Console.SetWindowSize(60, 100);
```

**Edit** You will get the exception if you try to set the Width or Height greater than the Maximum allow size. You can find out the Maximum allow Width and Height by [Console.LargestWindowWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.largestwindowwidth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Console.WindowHeight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.windowheight%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Console.LargestWindowWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.largestwindowwidth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Gets the largest possible number of console window columns, based on
>   the current font and screen resolution.

[Console.LargestWindowHeight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.largestwindowheight(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets the largest possible number of console window rows, based on the
>   current font and screen resolution.

Comment: That's exactly what i did but i don't know what it didn't work..

Comment: What values you are passing, where you have that code? It would be better if you add the code you have.

Comment: 'public static void Main (string[] args)
  { 
   Console.SetWindowSize (100,44);
   Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
   start:
   stopwatch.Start();
   int[,] sudokuTable = new int[9, 9];
   string[,] sudokuTableS = new string[9, 9];
   for (int i = 0; i < sudokuTable.GetLength(0); i++) 
   {    
    for (int j = 0; j < sudokuTable.GetLength(1); j++) 
    {     
     sudokuTable [i, j] = 0;
    }     
   }'

Comment: Use try catch block to make sure you do not get any exception and debug the code, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx